# The difference of using MotionEvent.getAction() method

Tags: android, multi-touch, motionevent

What is the difference between the two approaches below?

```
 int action1 = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

 int action2 = event.getAction();
```

Comment: Note: `event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK` is the same as `getActionMasked()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17384983/3681880), also.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ACTION_MASK` is used to separate the actual action and the pointer identifier (e.g. first finger touched, second finger touched, etc.) The first 8 bits of the value returned in [getAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29) is the actual action part, and so when you bitwise-AND it with the [action mask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MASK) (= 11111111 = 255 = 0xff), you are left with only the action and none of the pointer information.

Keep in mind here that `&` is used as an arithmetic operator (bitwise) and not a logical operator (single `&` is a perfectly valid logical operator in Java, as is `&&`).`

Comment: Ok, but I dont know whats the point of masking since I can compare directly action2 with MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Comment: You don't need to use it if you aren't supporting multitouch in most cases.