# In Android, what is the difference between getAction() and getActionMasked() in MotionEvent?

Tags: android, touch, motionevent

I am confused by the two methods in Android. It
seems that both methods tell you what kind of event it is,
i.e., whether it is a down or up event.

When will I use which?

```
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
```

Don't quote the documentation please, because I read it, and I don't see any parameter I can supply to either of the methods to get something different.

```
public final int getAction ()
```

and

```
public final int getActionMasked()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, they both return the action (up/down etc.), but `getAction()` may return the action with pointer information, in which case the events may be a little different. `getActionMasked()` will always return "simple" actions with the pointer information "masked out" (get it?). You would then call `getPointerIndex()` on the same event to get the index of the pointer. Note that you will most commonly see this on multi-touch devices with multiple points of contact (pointers). The pointer index is essentially a way of matching events to contact points so you can tell them apart.

Comment: Additional bit fields in the return value; the action and pointer index are returned in the same integer. Android defines a set of bit masks to extract them (which is essentially what getActionMasked does)

Answer (score 56):

**getAction()** returns a pointer id and an event (i.e., up, down, move) information.

**getActionMasked()** returns just an event (i.e., up, down, move) information.  Other info is masked out.

For example:

**getAction()** returns **0x0105**.
**getActionMasked()** will return **0x0005**, which is 0x0105 && **ACTION_MASK**.

1. The value of ACTION_MASK is 0xFF.  It masks the following actions.

   - ACTION_DOWN 0, UP 1, MOVE 2
   - ACTION_POINTER_DOWN 5, UP 6
2. The value of ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK is 0xFF00.  It masked the pointer ID from following deprecated constants.

   - ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN 0x0005
   - ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN 0x0105
   - ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN 0x0205
   - ...

Comment: I don't see it yet: why would I ever want to use getActionMasked()? does that ever have any advantage over getAction()?

Comment: @peedee With `getAction()`, you have to bitshift/mask to separate these two pieces of data; whereas with  `getActionMasked()` and `getActionIndex()` you get them separately (but probably at a higher runtime cost, due to two separate function calls). I would imagine that the combined representation returned by `getAction()` is what is used internally in the Android OS, since having two values combined this way is more storage- and cache-efficient on mobile hardware, bearing in mind that the touch API also stores a history of recent touch events, so there may be many of these data to be stored..