# Android OnTouch MotionEvent Actions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

So I think I have a very simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an `ImageView` and I am using it's `setOnTouchListener` method (`OnTouch`).

How can I differentiate between the `ACTION_DOWN` event and `ACTION_MOVE` event?

Even when I just click (touch) on the `ImageView`, `ACTION_MOVE` event gets called.

My goal is to open something(do anything) when the user clicks on it and move it when user holds it and moves it.

```
private int initialX;
private int initialY;
private float initialTouchX;
private float initialTouchY;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = params.x;
            initialY = params.y;
            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            return true;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           return true;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
           params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
           mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mImgFloatingView, params);

           // Log.d("Params", "X: " + params.x + ".  Y: " + params.y + ".");

          if(params.x == initialX && params.y == initialY) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: ACTION_DOWN is called when you first put your finger on the screen. Then if you keep your finger on the screen and start to move it, ACTION_MOVE is called

Comment: I understand that but my issue is that when I just tap on the `ImageView`, first ACTION_DOWN gets called and then ACTION_MOVE. That happens even when I only just tap (click), not move. Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

As others have said, `ACTION_MOVE` is called along with `ACTION_DOWN` because of the sensitivity of the device and the inherent unsensitivity of big fingers. This is known as [touch slop](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#vc). The results you want can be obtained by adjusting the thresholds for time and distance moved. Alternatively, you could use a [gesture detector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect).

### OnTouch MotionEvent Actions

Based on the title of the question, I came here looking for a quick reference for the `onTouch` `MotionEvent` actions. So here is a snippet copied from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

### Notes:

- The above code could be used in an activity or a subclassed view. If subclassing a view is not desired, then the same motion events can be tracked by adding an `OnTouchListener` to the view. (example also taken from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html))

  ```
    View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
    myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // ... Respond to touch events
            return true;
        }
    });
  ```
- [Difference between `getAction()` and `getActionMasked()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384983/android-what-is-the-difference-between-getaction-and-getactionmasked-in-moti)
- Returning `true` means that future events will still be processed. So if you returned `false` for `ACTION_DOWN` then all other events (like move or up) would be ignored.

### Further reading

- [Using Touch Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html): This is a series of official lessons in the documentation. It is an essential read for understanding how to correctly handle touch events and gestures.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that View.OnTouchListener will send you ALL events. If you tap and move by only 1 pixel, it'll be registered as a ACTION_MOVE.

You will need to implement some logic to determine a 'hold' action - waiting 100ms or something similar - after which a 'drag' action can proceed. Before that time, it should just be a 'click' action.